# How to travel through the signal light in fastest way?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am thinking of a simple two-way road with a pedestrian crossroad and a signal light. my idea to travel through the signal light in the fastest way is to minimize the duration caused by several factors. For example, the acceleration delay, de-acceleration delay, also consider the delay of the signal light duration. the total delay can be presented as a function with several delay components like $$f=d_1+d_2+d_3.$$
And by taking the derivative, you can find the best speed. But I am not sure how can I consider the situation when a car is in a queue. what should be the factor that I need to include

Comment: I'm a little confused: why would you de-accelerate after traveling through the intersection? Wouldn't you just keep on driving? Or do you have to come to a complete stop just as you clear the intersection?

Comment: Sorry for being a little bit unclear the order is messed up. I mean, when you see a red light, you got to deaccelerate from let's say, 50MPH to 0 and wait in the queue, and then until the green light pops out, you start to accelerate and go on.

Comment: Do you know how long the red light lasts? If so, one strategy would be to decelerate in such a way that you reach the intersection just as the light turns green, and then speed up again (don't try this in real life, people tend to run red lights)

Comment: lets say 50 seconds